# XSRF with AngularJS: DocuSign API Embedded View Client-Side implementation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, csrf, docusignapi

I have an AngularJS application that is utilizing the DocuSign Embedded Signing REST API to open a tab with the embedded document to DocuSign after the user completes a form.

I have looked around StackOverflow on some topics to help, but I can't find anything like my implementation.

I continue to get a 401 error on login, and I'm pretty sure it's because of CORS being blocked.
Any help is appreciated!

Here is my DocuSign factory:

```
app.factory('dsFactory', function($http) {
  return {
    login: function(templateId) {
      return $http({
        url: 'https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/login_information',
        method: 'GET',
        params: {
          'X-DocuSign-Authentication': {
            'DocuSignCredentials': {
              'UserName': 'xxx',
              'Password': 'xxx',
              'IntegratorKey': 'xxx'
            }
          }
        }
      });
    },
    envelope: function(baseUrl, templateId, recipientName, templateRoleName) {
      var url = baseUrl + "/envelopes";
      return $http({
        url: url,
        method: 'POST',
        params: {
          "emailSubject": "DocuSign API call - Embedded Sending Test",
          "templateId": templateId,
          "templateRoles": [{
            "email": "xxx",
            "name": recipientName,
            "roleName": templateRoleName
          }],
          "status": "sent"
        }
      });
    },
    getUrl: function(baseUrl, envelopeId, recipientName) {
      var url = baseUrl + "/envelopes/" + envelopeId + "/views/recipient";
      return $http({
        url: url,
        method: 'POST',
        params: {
          "returnUrl": "http://www.docusign.com/devcenter",
          "authenticationMethod": "email",
          "email": "xxx",
          "userName": recipientName
        }
      });
    }
  };
});
```

And here is the promise chain to open a new tab with the embedded document view:

```
// Elaborate promise chain for DocuSign login and document url retrieval
    loginPromise = dsFactory.login($scope.templateId);
    loginPromise.then(
      function(payload) {
        $scope.dsBaseUrl = payload.data.loginAccounts[0].baseUrl;
        envelopePromise = dsFactory.envelope($scope.dsBaseUrl, $scope.templateId, $scope.businessName, 'Signer');
        envelopePromise.then(
          function(payload) {
            $scope.dsEnvelopeId = payload.data.envelopeId;
            urlPromise = dsFactory.getUrl($scope.dsBaseUrl, $scope.dsEnvelopeId, $scope.businessName);
            urlPromise.then(
              function(payload) {
                $scope.dsCompleteUrl = payload.data.returnUrl;
                window.open($scope.dsCompleteUrl);
              },
              function(errorPayload) {
                console.log('retrieve DS url failed' + '\n');
                console.log('Status: ' + errorPayload.status);
              }
            );
          },
          function(errorPayload) {
            console.log('retrieve DS envelopeId failed' + '\n');
            console.log('Status: ' + errorPayload.status);
          }
        );
      },
      function(errorPayload) {
        console.log('DS login failed' + '\n');
        console.log('Status: ' + errorPayload.status);
      }
    );
```

Any thoughts or assistance on how I can get this integration working?

Maybe something to do with the headers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is not specific to Angular.

1. If you can either use callback or ask target domain to add your domain in the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header. For your specific issue, I don't think you can ask DocuSign to do this. It leaves you with #2.
2. You can call the API from server side.

Angularjs https (browser)->your server->DocuSign API>your server->browser

Comment: Consider, in #1, that you can't properly protect your integrator key.  By using #2 you can keep that key server-side and prevent it from being leaked.